# SwiftUI - Value of type 'Text' has no member 'localized

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm following this [tutorial](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSI_LS3Yq8I) on localization which is in UIKit and I'm trying to apply it to my SwiftUI app.

I'm getting this error Value of type `Text` has no member `localized`. Not sure how to call this function for Swiftui Text.

```
Text("Hello").localized()
   
extension String {
   func localized() -> String {
       return NSLocalizedString( self,tableName: "Localizable", bundle: .main, value: self, comment: self)
       
   }
}
```

Comment: It's string extension so try this ``` Text("Hello".localized())```

Comment: Why do you do that, it is already localizable, just put translations of "Hello" into Localizable.strings files.